# Changes to questions (answer count, votes, etc) are not reflected when returning to question listings

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

My workflow is: open my tag, try to answer all new unanswered questions.

I know I can refresh to force the answer count to update, but it's unsettling to answer a question, return to the list, and find 0 answers.

Even opening the question and seeing the answer, and then returning, does not update the answer count, so it is not just a caching issue.

Comment: "So it is not just a caching issue" Wanna bet?

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition. But, the answer count is correct within the question view but not in the list of tagged questions. So, it is an inconsistency between views, not just a delay.

Comment: @Gordon have you considered that the server-side cache for some views is updated less frequently than others.  So sure, you could consider it an inconsistency, but it is an inconsistency by design

Comment: Server side? As stated above, if I refresh the tagged questions view, the count gets corrected, so I don't think that is it.

Comment: I'm retagging this as a feature-request and changing the title slightly.  What we should really do (and this is not too complex) is notify question listings when a question has changed.  We've been treating it conceptually like a webpage where going back did not automatically provide refreshed content.

Comment: This is something I plan to work on after the next release goes out.

Comment: Yeh, I do UI work. The expectations are much higher for apps than for the Web. Thanks for considering this.

Comment: @BrianNickel better remove the tag.